# Issue with android studio and radiogroup

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to make a simple app in android studio but running into trouble with layout whenever I place down a `RadioGroup`. In my first image here I've created a `RadioGroup`and dragged two `RadioButtons` into it by dragging them to the radiogroup option on the component tree trying to drop them into the radiogroup on the layout thing is impossible as the radiogroup is completely invisible on it.

[image]

I drag a button below it, lining it up with the center, and the box that shows where the buttons going to go shows it being below the radiogroup. But once I release the mouse button, the button im attempting to place ends up here.

[image]

I've been fighting with android studio for a while now but if I get the button even remotely close to the `RadioGroup` it gets catapulted up the screen, and I don't have enough room if I place the button way down low for my other elements.

tl;dr
radiogroups are catapulting any elements underneath them above them. its probably a layout or gravity issue or something like that. but I don't know how to fix it and would like my buttons to not be underneath all the other elements kthx.

Comment: please be more specific and type less

Comment: How can I be more specific? I've attached images and a full description of my issue.

Comment: I would suggest using the "text" tab and learn how to code your xml instead of trying to use the GUI. And pasting the actually layout code would help. But writing the xml is much more flexible and easier to do once you understand it.

Comment: perhaps post you xml file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the college course I'm in requires me to use the GUI. dumb, I know.

Comment: Does the course require you to use the GUI interface designer or is the requirement just to use Android Studio? If you look closely, there is a "Text" tab which allows you to view the XML text in Android Studio and you can edit it there directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing your issue, because you aren't providing enough information. But If you want the button to appear under your radio group, then in your xml file, give your radio group an id `android:id="@+id/radioGroup"` and in your button add `android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"` in your button.As your are using  Relative Layout by default it takes you top while dragging.Here is full Button view.

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yourRadioGroupId"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```